# Web Platform and IIS CAN'T FIND MANAGEMENT SERVER

Tags: iis, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to have the management service in the IIS Manager. I know that to do that I need to add and install it in the web platform installer.

I'm having a difficulty finding it. I've even installed IIS: Management Scripts and Tools and IIS: Management Tools hoping that Management service will show up but it won't. I've also installed Web Deploy 3.5.

Question is, where can I find the management service?

I'm using web platform 5.0.

Answer (score 6):

That management service icon only appears if you are managing a Windows Server.

Comment: Oh. I am using windows 8.... Thank you so much! That will save a lot of time. I will stick to windows 8 then and find alternatives to use web deploy there. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: @TDL why do you need management service in the first place? It is server only as it is only needed there. Web Deploy on Windows 8 contains most of the features except  some remote control. You don't need remote control to use Web Deploy immediately.

Comment: The reason is that I'm following the steps in this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy

Comment: @TDL, I was following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler
because I am trying to deploy my mvc web app to another computer. but I cant find the Management Service in IIS Manager or in Web Platform.