# Unable to see "Management Service" in IIS 10 (Windows 10)

Tags: iis

I have windows 10 (pro) and IIS 10 installed on Server A. I was trying to publish a Web API from Visual Studio 2015 on Machine B to Server A, but I get the following error.

web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("172.26.50.17") . On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.

I understood from googling that the web server need to have Management Service installed and running. I have installed web platform installed and I can see that the "Web depoy 3.6 without bundled SQL support(latest)" component installed.

But I still do not see management service icon under "management" section on IIS. Could anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: __IIS remote management is not supported__ on client Windows (Desktop) operating systems. Please see - [Web Platform and IIS CAN'T FIND MANAGEMENT SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34118084/465053) & [Is it possible to enable the IIS remote management icons in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1131098/374397)

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by installing the Web **Platform Installer (Web PI).**

Then you can add a lot of tools using this Web PI. One of those tools is **Management Service** which can be enabled via Web PI.

If you do that and still cannot see the Management Service, **try closing and opening the IIS Manager** again.

**UPDATE:**
For Windows 10 and later, see the @RBT comment below.

Comment: This will _not_ work on Windows 10. `Management Service` is supported only on Server flavor of Windows operating systems. Please see - [Web Platform and IIS CAN'T FIND MANAGEMENT SERVER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34118084/465053) & [Is it possible to enable the IIS remote management icons in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1131098/374397)

Comment: "_The Microsoft Web Platform Installer (WebPI) was retired on December 31, 2022_" - https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed